# What is a Unit for Web Application Client

Tags: browser

What do you call a single hardware with lan port/wifi, touchscreen display and whose sole purpose is to view websites? or is there such devices in the current market or do we have to improvise one?

History:
I am a web developer and not actually a fan of hardwares. I develop web applications for my company, and since we are moving into making IoT projects, I just thought that having said unit will make our projects cost-efficient compared to a whole desktop whose function is to solely serve my web applications. Was searching and ended up in kiosks for windows and android, but I still think I can cut the price if the feature is only for browsing my web apps.
If it matters, we use PHP in server-side, w/ jquery & css on the client side.

Comment: @Seth it maybe is, but a regular tablet has camera, mic, speaker, and a bunch of not-so-useful pre-installed apps (else, you may be referring to a specific tablet). I'm looking for something without those features to *possibly* cut the price, as well as to prevent clients from doing anything else. Really, we can't control those employees. I just wanted something with human interface like touchscreen and which can render my web applications. No extras.

Answer (score 0):

One version of what you are describing is a "point of sale" terminal. They are usually all-in-one integrated terminals such as [these from Advantech](https://buy.advantech.eu/widget.aspx?widgetid=1543#hospitality).

They are rarely cheaper than "standard" computer boxes due to the rather custom nature of the devices and requirements for ruggedness due to being in high-footfall areas. They are designed far more for the task than a general workstation PC with cheap monitor.

Alternative terms would be [Kiosk PC](https://www.google.com/search?q=Kiosk%20PC) and [HMI (Human Machine Interface) PCs](https://www.google.com/search?q=HMI%20PC) such as [these](https://www.onlogic.com/uk-en/markets/manufacturing/human-machine-interface-hmi/).

They can be more cost efficient because they *should* be more reliable than a "standard" PC in the same area, but they most likely will have a higher initial cost for equivalent hardware.